# Is there a two variable polynomial with range $(0,\infty)$? From 'Real Analysis - Miklos Laczkovich and Vera T. Sos'

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

I would assume that this question is implicitly also asking that the polynomial's domain is not restricted (so the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$). This question is labeled as (H S) in the book, which I don't know what it means but might as well stand for stupid hard.

**Attempt 1** (brute force): Maybe $f(x,y) = \sum(\text{some polynoms})^2$

Reasoning is quite easy here, sum of some squares would be non-negative. Just need that that at least one these squared polynomials are non-zero when the others are zero. So let us try this (assume $b \neq 0$):

$$
f(x,y)=(ax+b)^2 + \left( kx(y+1) \right)^2 + \left( (x+1)y \right)^2
$$

At $(0,0);(-1,-1);(-1,y);(x,-1)$ this polynomial is > 0, good. Now, need to prove that $\exists(x,y):f(x,y)=\varepsilon,\forall \varepsilon >0$. I find this easier when forcing $y=0$, so we only work with one variable. What we have then is:

$$
(ax+b)^2 +(kx)^2 - \varepsilon = 0 \\
(a^2+k^2)x^2 + 2abx +(b^2-\varepsilon)=0
$$
Then quadratic formula yields some terms, but more importantly the discriminant is:

$$
\sqrt{4a^2b^2-4(a^2+k^2)(b^2-\varepsilon)}
$$

We want the discriminant to terms under the square root to be non-negative so that we get real roots. This will lead to:

$$
a^2\varepsilon > k^2(b^2-\varepsilon)\\
\varepsilon > \frac{k^2b^2}{a^2+k^2}
$$

Which I think is bad, because then we have to vary $a,b,k$ with as $\varepsilon$ changes. We need three fixed constants for $a,b,k$. I'm not sure at what point my approach was hopeless, but this is a dead-end I think.

I will attempt this question further, definitely not going to try to construct the polynomial again. Though I attempted to prove True, so my next attempt will be to shoot for False. I will appreciate some hints though (especially whether I should try to prove for true or false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an example, it is enough to find a sum of two squares where the terms cannot both vanish simultaneously, yet the sum can be made arbitrarily small e.g. $\,p(x,y)=x^2 + (xy+1)^2\,$ with $\,p(x,\frac{-1}{x})=x^2\,$ for $\,x \ne 0\,$.